# Unable to retrieve MySQL data in PHP site

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code which a login page will call to run this php script. 
However, the code keep telling me that the user name and password are incorrect. 
Therefore i added in the echo to see what value it is getting from the DB.
Apprently the query return '' for both username and password.

I have only 1 record in the DB called 'appthub_db', table named 'tbl_user' with table columns 'username' and 'password'.

I dont get an connection error(I think). I don't know what is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<?php 
include_once("DBConnection.php"); 
session_start(); //always start a session in the beginning 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{ 
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) //Validating inputs using PHP code 
{ 
echo 
"Incorrect username or password"; //
header("location: LoginForm.php");//You will be sent to Login.php for re-login 
} 
$inUsername = $_POST["username"]; // as the method type in the form is "post" we are using $_POST otherwise it would be $_GET[] 
$inPassword = $_POST["password"]; 

echo $inUsername;
echo nl2br ("\n ");
echo $inPassword; 
echo nl2br ("\n ");

$stmt= $db->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM tbl_user WHERE username = ?"); //Fetching all the records with input credentials
$stmt->bind_param("s", $inUsername); //bind_param() - Binds variables to a prepared statement as parameters. "s" indicates the type of the parameter.
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($UsernameDB, $PasswordDB); // Binding i.e. mapping database results to new variables
//Compare if the database has username and password entered by the user. Password has to be decrypted while comparing.

echo "DBUsername:" ;
echo $UsernameDB ;
echo nl2br ("\n ");
echo "DBPassword:" ;
echo $PasswordDB;

if ($stmt->fetch() && password_verify($inPassword, $PasswordDB)) 
{
$_SESSION['username']=$inUsername; //Storing the username value in session variable so that it can be retrieved on other pages
header("location: UserProfile.php"); // user will be taken to profile page
}
else
{
echo "Incorrect username or password";
?><br>
<a href="LoginForm.php">Login</a>
<?php 
} 
} 
?>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Run the `$stmt->fetch()` statement in a separate if statement to check first if there is a row in the database and to retrieve the hash from the database. This way you can investigate if the problem is that no rows are returned OR if `password_verify()` is returning false. Because now you don't know which condition in the `if` statement is returning `false`.

Comment: You're echoing the variables before you call `fetch()`, so they won't be set yet.

Comment: @Barmar ok, when i put the echo to see the values after the fetch(), the values are the same. But somehow the condition if ($stmt->fetch() && password_verify($inPassword, $PasswordDB)) fails.

Comment: Did you call `password_hash()` when storing the password in the DB?

Comment: Oh i realised password_verify need a $hash, which is why it is failing...i will add the password_hash key into my code